# My AdMob ad is not showing for more than three days

Tags: google-play, admob, ads, google-ads-api

I want to advertise my app on AdMob. On June 9 I created a campaign and on the next day added to my Google Ads account $27. But still there are no impressions. Am I doing something wrong, or I just need to wait more?

[image: AdMob]

[image]

I also thought maybe I just need more than $27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to say why that happens, some possible reasons (just from my experience):

1. Your account is disable by platform or payment status is wrong, as no delivery happens, this may be most possible reason
2. Your campaign has too low bidding price, or too narrow targeting, which is hard to win opportunity
3. Your campaign has wrong time setting, like start/end date

You should ask Admob support team for it, or before that, you may create another campaign in an active account to double check campaign creation process